# Clear Password Fields if errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a regular signup form with virtual_attributes:

```
attr_accessor :password_confirmation

def password
  @password
end

def password=(password)
  @password=self.crypted_password = User.encrypt(@password=pass, create_new_password_salt)
end
```

I would like to clear the password fields of the form when there are errors on password. I figured out how to make the password field not show on error using return, but I can't figure out how to make the password_confirmation field return if there are errors on the password field.

the views are just simple

```
<% form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.password_field :password %>
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Can you post some of your view code? You may just want to set the password and password_confirmation to nil before you display those fields.

Comment: But then if there were errors on other fields, they would have to enter the password again. Which is not unreasonable I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not entirely clear to me how your current password validation works, but how about something like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  validate :password_confirmation_matches

  def password_confirmation_matches
    if password != password_confirmation
      errors.add_to_base("You did not correctly confirm your password")
      self.password_confirmation = self.password = nil
    end
  end
end
```

Would that work for you?